# Kubernetes deployment failure - how to inspect?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

I have a deployment file and when I do `kubectl apply -f` my pods don't get deployed after a few restart and crashes. Hence my questions:

1- If I set the replicas to 1, is there a way to have an "interactive" mode where I can see in my terminal what's going on?

2- Is there a way to limit - in the deployment file - the number of restart? This can be specified for pods (restartPolicy...) but not for deployment apparently?

3- Any troubleshooting guidelines? For example, how to check that the values in the config maps are properly picked up?
Many thanks - Christian

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use

`# kubectl get pods -n <your namespace>`

command to see your pods. To see them "interactive", you can use `watch` command with `kubectl` like this;

`# watch kubectl get pods -n <your-namespace>`

2) Currently, there is no way to limit the pod restart counts.

3) You can see what's going on with your deployments and pods while they are created with `kubectl describe` command.

For getting info about pod status,

```
# kubectl get pods -n <your-namespace> --> here you can get your pod's name.
# kubectl describe po <pod-name> -n <your-namespace>
```

For getting info about deployment status,

```
# kubectl get deployments -n <your-namespace> --> here you can get your deployment's name.
# kubectl describe deployment <deployment-name> -n <your-namespace>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If your pods have managed to actually be scheduled and start, but the app inside the container crashes, then usually `kubectl logs` will be able to show you the logs that were written to stdout / stderr inside the container.

E.g. `kubectl logs -n your-namespace your-pod-name`

You can also tail or head logs. E.g.

- `kubectl logs -n your-namespace your-pod-name --tail=50` (for the last 50 log lines)
- `kubectl logs -n your-namespace your-pod-name -f` (follow logs)

Otherwise if your container has failed to be scheduled by kubernetes, then describe is probably a better option.

E.g. `kubectl -n your-namespace describe your-pod-name`

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#interacting-with-running-pods) are some other useful examples around interacting with pods that are running (and have not crashed yet).